# How can I synchronize the clipboard of terminal applications on a server without X?

Tags: ssh, vim, tmux, clipboard, headless

On machines with X server, I've used the `selection` clipboard to synchronize copy/paste across GUI and terminal programs. Now I have a server without X where I'd like to synchronize copy/paste across terminal apps, e.g. `zsh` and `vim` and `tmux`. Later, I hope to further sync that clipboard with the system clipboard of the Mac I'm using to SSH into the linux server.

Is such a setup possible? Concretely,

- Is the a shared clipboard for Linux to synchronize copy/paste across terminal applications without having X11 running?
- Is there a tool similar to `xsel` and `xclip` for this?
- Even better, is there a tool like these that works with and without running X server, allowing me to use the same configuration/dotfiles for both scenarios?
- Finally, and I admit this is a bit of a separate issue, how could this clipboard be synchronized with that of an SSH client?

Answer (score 1):

There is no common clipboard for terminal applications. Each of tmux, zsh and vim have their own clipboard.

tmux has a mechanism to send copied text to the external terminal with an escape sequence (the `set-clipboard` option) and also to read the clipboard (`refresh-client -l`). Only X terminals support this feature and not all of them.

tmux also supports the same escape sequence (OSC 52) allowing applications inside tmux to read the most recent paste buffer (if `set-clipboard` is set to `on`). However, to my knowledge few, if any, applications use this.

tmux also allows you to save paste buffers to a file or to stdout with the `save-buffer` command and load them with the `load-buffer` command. This is probably easier to use than OSC 52.

I expect it would be possible to write scripts for zsh and vim to use one or other of these features to set and retrieve their clipboard.

So yes, you could rig something together by running everything inside tmux, using tmux to hold the clipboard and writing some scripts to get and set it from vim, zsh and so on, but I think you will need to do it yourself, there is no existing solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Using a file as common clipboard seems like a good approach. Do you know if this could be synchronized with my SSH client? If I understand your suggestion correctly, tools on the server would all read the file on paste. But this would likely be too slow for the client, so syncing in the background on copy would be better.

Comment: I don't mean using a file, I meant using tmux's paste buffers, although you might be able to use a file, the idea would be the same. I don't know what you mean by synchronizing with an ssh client. ssh doesn't have a clipboard. Are you using a combined terminal and ssh client like `putty` and you want to set the system clipboard where the terminal is running?